# How to generate 12 digit sequence number in java

Tags: java

I want to generate 12 digit mobile number. It's start with 910.
Ex: 910000000001,
910000000002,
910000000003.

It is possible in java?

Comment: where are you stuck?

Comment: yes it is possible but what sequence range you want to generate,explain more about your problem.

Comment: @Mohammad Oghli: i have save method,in that i want to generate one 12 digit seq mobile number. i mean first time calling save method it generate 910000000000 and next time calling it generate 910000000001 and next time 910000000002,etccc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do.

If you want to just get the nextNumber: I would suggest AtomicLong.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#AtomicLong-long-

```
class GetNextNumber {
    private static AtomicLong numberGenerator = new AtomicLong(910000000000L);

    public static long getNext() {
        return numberGenerator.getAndIncrement();
    }
}
```

If you need random numbers (with possible duplicated, you can use the ThreadLocalRandom as suggested by Ravi.

Comment: I want to generate sequential like (ABC00001, ABC00002 ....) . how can i do this? please could you reply me?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to generate all numbers in sequence from 910000000000 to 910999999999?

You could do something like this.

```
    long counter = 910000000000L;
    while(counter <= 910999999999L) // You can change this constant if you want the loop to break sooner
    {
        //Print, add to list, whatever
        counter++;
    }
```

Edit: It needs to be `long`

Comment: Doesn't work because `int` cannot hold such large numbers. Limit is `2147483647`, see [Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)

Comment: Yeah i fixed that :)

Comment: @ThomasFritsch I changed it to a `long` about 5 minutes ago, is it not visible?

Comment: You will need `L` on the constants as they are long literals.

Comment: @Oscar Lundberg: i have one method. in that i placed your code. it's going to increase but not stopping. How to break it.

Comment: It will break when `counter > 910999999999L`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for random number 12 digit number starting with 9 you can make use of [ThreadLocalRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html)

```
System.out.println( ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong( 910000000001L, 910999999999L ) );
```